# Insert a unique key, a couple of columns and the sum of sub-query into a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using postgres DB and, in the middle of a DB migration, I have an empty table `tableB` which I want to fill from data existing in another `tableA`.

`tableB` has the following columns

```
CREATE TABLE contributors (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    pps double precision NOT NULL,
    contributor_user_id bigint,
    project_id bigint
);
```

while `tableA` has the following columns

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    assigned_ppoints double precision NOT NULL,
    state integer,
    contributor_id bigint,
    project_id bigint
);
```

All `*_id` are actually foreign keys.

I need to add one new row on `tableB` for each existing combination of `contributor_id` and `project_id` of `tableA` as follows

- in `project_id`, `project_id` of `tableA`
- in `contributor_user_id`, I need `contributor_id` of `tableA`
- in `pps` i need the *sum* of `assigned_ppoints` of that `contributor_user_id` and `project_id` for which `state=2` within `tableA`.

My starting (and very distant) point is

```
INSERT INTO tableB (id, project_id, contributor_user_id, pps) 
SELECT MAX(id) FROM tableB, project_id, contributor_id, SUM(assigned_ppoints)
FROM tableA WHERE project_id=1 AND state=2 AND contributor_id=1;
```

Which is wrong, and would only add one row corresponding to one combination of `project_id` and `contributor_id`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Aggregate filter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

```
select
    max(id),
    contributor_id,
    project_id,
    sum(assigned_ppoints) filter (where state = 2)
from t
group by 2,3
```

For 9.3 and previous versions:

```
select
    max(id),
    contributor_id,
    project_id,
    sum(assigned_ppoints * (state = 2)::integer)
from t
group by 2,3
```

Comment: it works perfectly, I had to do 
INSERT INTO tableB (id, project_id, contributor_user_id, pps) 
SELECT 
 (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tableB) AS maxId, 
 project_id, 
 contributor_id, 
 SUM(assigned_ppoints) FILTER (WHERE state=2)
FROM tableA
GROUP BY project_id,contributor_id;

Comment: I still have the problem that the (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tableB) returns the same value for all new rows, so all ids are equal. Any clues?

Comment: I had also the problem that the id on the new table had to be unique. I have solved this creating a new sequence and using nextval('tableB_seq').

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a structure like this:

```
insert into A (...)
select
  something_B,
  another_B,
  (select something_C from C where ...) as subselect_C
from B
where ...
;
```

As you see now you'd do a subquery for every matching row of `B`.